# Automatic Token Invalidation

Tags: jwt, okta

I have a scenario where a user's role is authorized using the JWT claims. 
However, how to invalidate the JWT token when the user's role is revoked by an administrator
and prompt the user to login again?

Answer (score 2):

One approach here is to maintain a blacklist cache of revoked JWT tokens.  Should a user's access need to be revoked at a point where the `exp` claim in his token not already be expired, the administrator would then add his JWT to a cache.  This also means that part of the authorization and/or authentication process now would involve hitting this blacklist cache, to make sure that any incoming JWT has not already been revoked.  However, if you structure things well, the penalty for hitting the cache would be small (about 1/100 the penalty for hitting a database).

This blacklist cache can also be used to store the JWT of users who have signed out with valid tokens still extant.  Again, this is a scenario where a user has logically signed out, but the `exp` claim in his token still says the JWT is alive.  Adding the JWT to the same blacklist cache is one way of also handling this use case.